# Apache 2.2 + Varnish not listening to 8080 port

Tags: apache, varnish

I'm running apache 2.2 with multiple VirtualHosts and varnish cache on Centos 6.6. The problem is I can't get this to work.

```
httpd.conf:
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName xxxx.com
ServerAlias www.xxxx.com
```

Varnish is set to run on 80 port. DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80

`default.vcl:
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";}`

etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
2a01:xxx:190:xxx8::2
5.0.100.000
```

Whenever I try to reach my virtualhost I see var/www/html content.
What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Seems there was more Listen params in ssl.conf, commented out all except Listen 443, everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to set your **[DocumentRoot](https://github.com/SuriyaaKudoIsc/localhost/blob/Windows-8.1/Server/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf#L547)** on Apache `httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot var/www/html
```

*Stop Apache completely and start it again:*

```
httpd -k stop
httpd -k start
```

*Or restart it:*

```
httpd -k restart
```

Comment: default DocumentRoot is set to "/var/www/html", VirtualHost have /home/xxx/public_html documentroot

Comment: Not working at all.. Maybe this is somekind of varnish issue?

Comment: By the way I can access virtualhost if I point a port to domain. example.com:8080 works, but example.com shows default var/www

Comment: Set your IP address to your server: https://github.com/SuriyaaKudoIsc/localhost/blob/Windows-8.1/Server/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf#L58

Comment: What I can see that varnish kills itself after start.. Don't know why

Comment: Attempts to set only one VirtualHost and add later other VirtualHosts to see where the error is.

Comment: Varnish starts if i stop httpd, but later i can't start httpd - Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address xxxxxxxx:80 .. why it wants to listen 80 if I set 8080 in config.

Comment: Which version of Varnish do you use?

Comment: varnishd (varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8)

Comment: Failed to start apache :
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address x.x.xxx.171:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[FAILED]

Comment: Try to upgrade "Varnish Cache 3.0.7 revision f544cd8" to "Varnish Cache 4.0.3": https://www.varnish-cache.org/content/varnish-cache-403!

Comment: You set up your listening sockets wrong: "no listening sockets available"!